# Out of bound address when directly reading from array

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, cuda

I am developing a CUDA application which has some routines for allocation and deallocation of arrays in shared memory.

In this application (that, I am sorry, I cannot make available), I have a class that encapsulate a chunk of memory as an array. This class has a `count` method that counts the number of elements that matches a certain value.

So, imagine something like (which is an actual part of the whole class)

```
template <class Type>
struct Array {
    // ...

    Type &operator[](int i) { return data_[i]; }
    Type operator[](int i) const { return data_[i]; }

    size_t count(const Type &val) const {
        size_t c = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len_; ++i)
            if (data_[i] == val)
                ++c;
        return c;
    }

    void print(const char *fmt, const char *sep, const char *end) const {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len_ - 1; ++i) {
            printf(fmt, data_[i]);
            printf(sep);
        }
        printf(fmt, _data[len_ - 1]);
        printf(end);
    }
private:
    Type *data_;
    size_t len_;
};
```

Assumed that the memory I am accessing is correctly allocated (shared memory allocated at runtime, passing the dimension to the kernel), that is big enough to contain data and that `data_` points to an aligned (wrt `Type`) region *inside* the shared memory. I checked this multiple times, and these assumptions shall be valid (but feel free to ask more checkings).

Now, while testing the code I found something very strange:

- When explicitly assigning values using `operator[]`, and reading them using `operator[] const`, no issues arise.
- When reading data using `print`, no issues arises.
- When calling `count()`, program crashes and `Address ADDR is out of bounds` is reported by cuda-memcheck, caused by `Invalid __global__ read of size x` (x = sizeof(Type)). The ADDR is inside the shared memory buffer, so it should be valid.
- If, inside `count`, I replace `data_[i]` with `(*this)[i]`, the program runs fine and no crash occurs.

Now, I have absolutely no idea about this could happen, and I have no idea about what to check to see what is happening behind the scenes... Why reading directly crashes? Why using `operator[]` does not? And why reading (directly?) inside `print` do not crashes?

I know this question is hard and I am sorry to provide this little information about the code... But feel free to ask for detail, I will try to answer as much as I can. Any idea or suggestion is welcome, because it is days I am trying to solve and this is as far as I could get.

I am using two different GPUs to test this code, one with capability 2.1 and one with 3.5 (the latter one is giving me detailed information about this crash, while the first one does not). CUDA 5.0

EDIT: I have located a minimal example where this error happens. Curiously, the error appears when compiling with sm_20 and sm_35, but not on sm_30. The GPU I am using has cap 3.5

```
/* Compile and run with:
  nvcc -g -G bug.cu -o bug -arch=sm_20 # bug!
  nvcc -g -G bug.cu -o bug -arch=sm_30 # no bug :|
  nvcc -g -G bug.cu -o bug -arch=sm_35 # bug!
  cuda-memcheck bug

Here's the output (skipping the initial rows) I get
Ctor for 0x3fffc10 w/o alloc, data 0x10000c8
Calling NON CONST []
Calling NON CONST []
Fill with [] ok
Fill with raw ok
Kernel launch failed with error:
        unspecified launch failure
========= Invalid __global__ write of size 8
=========     at 0x00000188 in /home/bio/are/AlgoCUDA/bug.cu:26:array<double>::fill(double const &)
=========     by thread (0,0,0) in block (0,0,0)
=========     Address 0x010000c8 is out of bounds
=========     Device Frame:/home/bio/are/AlgoCUDA/bug.cu:49:kernel_bug(unsigned long) (kernel_bug(unsigned long) : 0x8c0)
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib/libcuda.so (cuLaunchKernel + 0x3dc) [0xc9edc]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0 [0x13324]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0 (cudaLaunch + 0x182) [0x3ac62]
=========     Host Frame:bug [0xbb8]
=========     Host Frame:bug [0xaa7]
=========     Host Frame:bug [0xac4]
=========     Host Frame:bug [0xa07]
=========     Host Frame:/lib/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xfd) [0x1ec4d]
=========     Host Frame:bug [0x8c9]
=========
========= Program hit error 4 on CUDA API call to cudaDeviceSynchronize 
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib/libcuda.so [0x26a180]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/cuda-5.0/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0 (cudaDeviceSynchronize + 0x1dd) [0x441fd]
=========     Host Frame:bug [0xa0c]
=========     Host Frame:/lib/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xfd) [0x1ec4d]
=========     Host Frame:bug [0x8c9]
=========
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors


(cuda-gdb) set cuda memcheck on
(cuda-gdb) run
Starting program: /home/bio/are/AlgoCUDA/bug 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
[New Thread 0x7ffff5c25700 (LWP 23793)]
[Context Create of context 0x625870 on Device 0]
[Launch of CUDA Kernel 0 (kernel_bug<<<(1,1,1),(1,1,1)>>>) on Device 0]
Memcheck detected an illegal access to address (@global)0x10000c8

Program received signal CUDA_EXCEPTION_1, Lane Illegal Address.
[Switching focus to CUDA kernel 0, grid 1, block (0,0,0), thread (0,0,0), device 0, sm 12, warp 0, lane 0]
0x0000000000881928 in array<double>::fill (this=0x3fffc10, v=0x3fffc08) at bug.cu:26
26                              data[i] = v;
*/

#include <stdio.h>

extern __shared__ char totalSharedMemory[];

template <class Type>
struct array {
    // Create an array using a specific buffer
    __device__ __host__ array(size_t len, Type *buffer):
        len(len),
        data(buffer) {
        printf("Ctor for %p w/o alloc, data %p\n", this, data);
    }
    __device__ __host__ Type operator[](int i) const {
        printf("Calling CONST []\n");
        return data[i];
    }
    __device__ __host__ Type &operator[](int i) {
        printf("Calling NON CONST []\n");
        return data[i];
    }
    __device__ __host__ void fill(const Type &v) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) data[i] = v;
    }
    size_t len;
    Type *data;
};

__global__ void kernel_bug(size_t bytesPerBlock) {
    // This is a test writing to show that filling the memory
    // does not produce any error
    for (size_t i = 0; i < bytesPerBlock; ++i) {
        totalSharedMemory[i] = i % ('z' - 'a' + 1) + 'a';
        printf("[%p] %c\n", totalSharedMemory + i, totalSharedMemory[i]);
    }

    // 200 / 8 = 25 so should be aligned
    array<double> X(2, (double *)(totalSharedMemory + 200));
    X[0] = 2;
    X[1] = 4;
    printf("Fill with [] ok\n");
    X.data[0] = 1;
    X.data[1] = 0;
    printf("Fill with raw ok\n");
    X.fill(0); // Crash here
    printf("Fill with method ok\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Total memory required
    size_t bytesPerBlock = 686; // Big enough for 85 doubles
    kernel_bug<<<1, 1, bytesPerBlock>>>(bytesPerBlock);
    cudaError_t err = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Kernel launch failed with error:\n\t%s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: tested also with CUDA 4.2, the problem persists.

Comment: You don't show the code where you set len_, but in your print function you use len_ - 1, but in count you use len_. I suspect you have an off by one error in setting len_.

Comment: Delete your copy constructor and assignment operator and see if the problem persists, or you get compilation errors.

Comment: @Muscles, oh, good idea, but actually that is not the problem, as len_ in my test case is >1.

Comment: @NathanErnst copy constructor and assignment operator usage was under check, but I did as you suggested anyway: unluckily, nothing changes and the problem persists.

Comment: It was just a hunch that maybe your memory was freed by an errant copy. Not familiar enough with cuda to add any more. Good luck.

Comment: May I see your usage of this structure?

Comment: Cuda-memcheck reports `Invalid __global__ read of size x (x = sizeof(Type))` and you are using it on shared memory array. It means that compiler wasn't able to determine the pointer refers to shared memory. What about declaring `*data_;` as `extern __shared__ data_[]` ?

Comment: @stuhlo the point of my whole code is to manage the `extern __shared__ data`. So `*data_` should point to a subset of it. Being a data member, I cannot use the `__shared__` qualifier. I will post the usage of the structure shortly.

Comment: @stuhlo I have added an usage example. It is very very similar to my actual code, I just removed some parameters used to initialize the memory (again, sorry, but the code is a bit large and I could not provide it as a whole)

Comment: 2 comments above I meant that the point of the class was to manage an `extern __shared__ char buffer[]`, and `*data_` is local to a single array for accessing a subset of it. Since the buffer is a `char` and the `data_` is a template type, a cast would be required anyway to access the data, so it is more or less enforced to have such pointer.

Comment: @AkiRoss: Can you make a *simple, complete* repro case which shows this behaviour and post it here? If another code (ie. not your supa sekret application) does the same thing, then you should be writing a bug report, not a stack overflow question. If it doesn't, this is a debugging question,

Comment: @talonmies well it is two days that I am progressively trying to reduce the code to understand what is the problem and this is as far as I could get. I could try to reduce it further, even if it is pretty long to do, but I think the issue is precisely the one described here. I will try reducing it further anyway, eventually I will put it on github and make it available here.

Comment: @AkiRoss: You *might* have found a compiler bug. But if you can't write and provide code for a manageable size repro case that someone else can compile (and it sounds like it could be a trivially short repro case), then how can you or anyone else know?

Comment: Ok, I reduced the code a lot, now I can get the same error with 60 lines of code ;) All my *supa sekret* (lol) application seems not to be involved in that. But now the error is gone on a device (cap 2.1) and persists on the other (cap 3.5) (can this be related to more strict memory checking on GPUs with cap 3.x?)

Comment: @AkiRoss, Could you post the version of the CUDA driver you are using in these tests ? You can get this by doing `cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version` If you are using the 304.54 driver, could you try updating to the latest available drivers from nvidia.com? Also, could you post the small example that is hitting this issue ?

Comment: @Vyas, I am using 304.54 on the kepler machine, but I have to wait for the sysadmin to update the kernel. On my local machine I have the latest version. The code above *should* hit the issue, but we are experiencing troubles, because *that* code, that yesterday was buggy, today is not giving the bug. Other code still does, anyway.

Comment: Ok, an important question: this code make a huge work with pointers to shared memory, and I think that, maybe, some information is lost in this process. Now, I *am not using* the `volatile` keyword. Is it possible that the cause is there?

Comment: @Vyas, driver upgraded to 310.32, issue still present, but I am getting new and more detailed info about the call. I hope to find the crux now...

Comment: I tried running the code you posted, but I am not seeing the bug you mentioned. Are you still able to hit the issue with the sample code you posted ?

Comment: No, I have to work on a new code to find the bug (the original bug is still there). I will look for another one asap.

Comment: @AkiRoss: This basically unanswerable question has been sitting untouched for 10 months. Did you solve the problem? If you did, could you add your solution as a short answer. If you didn't, could you do something about it? It is a shame to see abandoned questions just filling up the unanswered list this this one.

Comment: The problem was not solved and a workaround has been used. I can check if things has changed, though.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem on linux with CUDA 5.0/driver 304.54. (using `-arch=sm_20`.  I did not try other targets)  I was not able to reproduce the problem with CUDA 5.5/driver 319.72 on an otherwise identical machine (OS, GPU).  **I suggest updating to CUDA 5.5**.  From my brief analysis, it appears to be a problem with `cuda-memcheck` in CUDA 5.0.  If I omit the `-G` switch when compiling the code, or do not run with `cuda-memcheck`, I am not able to reproduce the problem even on CUDA 5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue with the following:

RHEL 5.5, driver 304.54, CUDA 5.0, Quadro 5000 GPU.

I was not able to reproduce the issue with the following:

RHEL 5.5, driver 319.72, CUDA 5.5, Quadro 5000 GPU.

Please update your CUDA install to CUDA 5.5, and your driver to 319.72 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

While you are trying to pinpoint the crash, it'd be good to remove implicit conversion from 0 to 0.0 in the `X.fill(0);`call. It's valid C++, but CUDA could have troubles allocating temporaries in the function call operator. Indeed, skimming their docs I couldn't find an answer on where such temporaries are to be allocated -- global? device?
Likely it's not the problem, though, but... to be sure.

Comment: I removed the conversion, but that did not solve. Thanks for the idea anyway ;)